# Get byte array from Library.AssetForUrl()

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I try to use below code block for save video to gallery and after that get this video as an byte array. Bu I can't understand how Library.AssetForUrl() part works. How can I get the byte array from it?

```
 var Library = new ALAssetsLibrary();
    albumSave = await Library.WriteVideoToSavedPhotosAlbumAsync(outputFileUrl);
    Library.AssetForUrl (assetUrl, delegate(ALAsset asset) {
        long size = asset.DefaultRepresentation.Size;
        Console.WriteLine("Filename: " + asset.DefaultRepresentation.Filename);
        byte[] imgData = new byte[size];
        NSError nsError;
        IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(imgData.Length);

        asset.DefaultRepresentation.GetBytes(buffer, 0, (uint)size, out nsError);
        Console.WriteLine(nsError);
       Marshal.Copy(buffer, imgData, 0, imgData.Length);
    },
    (NSError err)=>
    {
    Console.WriteLine(err);
    }
```